# In this code, it is not taking input for i=0. It is directly going for i=1

Tags: c++, vector

in this code it is taking not taking input for i=0. It is taking input directly for i=1.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<string> x;
    string q;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        getline(cin,q);
        x.push_back(q);
        cout<<x.size();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
        cout<<x[i]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what "not taking input" or "taking input directly" means? Show some example input and output, and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: for i=0 it is directly printing x.size() it is not taking input for q. for ex-after i give input to n it directly prints x.size() not taking input to q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra "getline(cin,q);" statement before "for loop" so that it reads the pending line where you entered input for "cin>>n;" statement.

Your new code will be:-

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;
     vector<string> x;
 string q;
 getline(cin,q); // to read the pending line 
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {

   getline(cin,q);
    x.push_back(q);
    cout<<x.size();
 }
 for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
 cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is a more explicit alternative, but pretty ugly in practice: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. For any practical use can be written as `cin.ignore(1<<30, '\n');` though.